# I used to write poems. but i don't know how can we publish our hindi poem in India?

Tags: publishing, poetry

I used to write poems in Hindi but i don't know the way to publish them in India. Many times i tried on google or my local publisher but they do ask me to give them content.

Comment: Don't worry, People are known for their content. If your content is really powerful you will get publisher soon.

Comment: I am reading books of how to present our content in a better way.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? A quick search for "publish poems in india" produces a variety of valid approaches. In your comments, you hint that giving them content is a problem. Isn't it normal to do so? What is the real question behind your question?

Comment: Placing this on hold for now, since it's very unclear what you're asking. Please feel free to edit so it's more specific and we'll consider reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start saying or demo in front of people. If they will appreciate, you will known on a better height.

Comment: i said many time.

Comment: Good. then what is the problem?